# Is it possible to add ControlMaster to a JSch connection?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I've gotten myself into a situation where I need to reuse an existing session with JSch. I need a `shell` channel and a `SFTP` channel to share the same connection. Is it possible to implement ControlMaster within a JSch implementation? And if so, what options do I need to set? Would it be just like any other OpenSSH implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsch supports opening more than one channel through a single session (TCP connection to a remote SSH server). So, if the Jsch session just needs to be shared among different parts of the same program, that's not difficult to implement.

The OpenSSH ControlMaster feature lets the ssh client share its ssh session with *external* programs through a control socket. As of now, jsch doesn't directly support anything like that. If you wanted your jsch client to have such a feature, you'd have to implement it yourself.

OpenSSH has its own protocol for communications through the ControlMaster socket. If you wanted your implementation to interoperate with OpenSSH, you could implement the same protocol. The protocol is documented in a file named "PROTOCOL.mux" which is included with the OpenSSH source code. You can also find copies online by doing an Internet search for the name.